# How is the "travel mode" menu in Google Maps implemented?

Tags: html, css, menu

I see this type of menu all over the Internet as a way to filter out data:

[image: Four buttons used to select between driving, public transport, walking, and cycling]

Does it have a specific name? I'm particularly interested in seeing how the pushed in effect is achieved. I've gone through the Chrome developer tools but viewing the CSS applied Chrome only returns a few classes and not the id of the element.

Comment: Douglas Bowman has a nice blog post about designing earlier buttons for Gmail: http://stopdesign.com/archive/2009/02/04/recreating-the-button.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu type does not have a specific name as far as I know (although for all effects and purposes it is a set of [radio buttons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button)).

The pushed in effect is caused by an inset shadow and darker background color.

[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gnW67/8/)

Answer (score 3):

That menu is from Google maps.

It is what I might call an "icon" menu.

Buttons are not pushed in.

Instead, the images are swapped in and out depending on what is chosen.

Javascript is used to change the images and the content below the images.

Use Chrome and go to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.ca/).  Type in an address and then click **Get Directions**.  Once the buttons appear, right click on one of the button and choose **Inspect element**.  That will show you the code that Googe is using.

Answer (score 1):

The pushed effect is simply an image applied to the element when it's clicked

They're usually done with sprites

Here are some sprites from google

[image]

When the image is hovered/clicked a different spot on the image is used as the background for that element.